# Gridview error when fetching data from json. how to solve it?

Tags: android, json

I have a custom gridview in which I'm using : One image view and two text views. In one text view I'm putting data manually and in another text view i want to put data via json.
If in textview2 (json text) data is not there then gridview will give error..
How to do it? 
Or
How to hide gridview items if textview2 is empty during loading of json data?

Comment: Filter your data before passing to adapter...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide TextView element via property Visibility.
Like this:

```
 TextView tv2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv2);
 JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
        if (!jo.getString("text2").equals("null")) {
              tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: I know this thing. But if there is no data in textview2 inside gridview then it will give error.